# TextFieldTableCell завершить редактирование после изменения фокуса

Tags: java, javafx

Есть `TableView` , в ней по умолчанию возможно завершить редактирование ячейки таблицы только после нажатие клавиши enter, как можно реализовать то же по изменению фокуса?

```
final ObservableList<Record> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new Record("Carl"), new Record("Jon"));

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    TableView tableView = new TableView();
    tableView.setEditable(true);
    Scene scene = new Scene(tableView);

    TableColumn name = new TableColumn("name");


    name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Record,String>("name"));
    name.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    name.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Record, String>>() {
        public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Record, String> event) {
            event.getTableView().getItems().get(event.getTablePosition().getRow()).setName(event.getNewValue());
        }
    });

    tableView.getColumns().addAll(name);
    tableView.setItems(data);


    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setWidth(400);
    primaryStage.setHeight(400);
    primaryStage.setTitle("test");
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

Класс Record

```
private String name;


public String getName() {
        return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
}
```

Comment: А ты сам создаешь копнонет, в котором ты будешь редактировать текст?

Comment: У меня при запуске программы инициализируются количество ячеек и их содержание на основание данных из xml, конкретно вручную я их не создаю

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, минимальный компилируемый код.

Comment: @LEQADA добавил код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось, что это баг `TableView` и [висит он в багтрекере](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8089514) уже несколько лет. [Нашёл](https://gist.github.com/james-d/be5bbd6255a4640a5357) обход. Выглядит как-то так:

```
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellEditEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.TablePosition;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;


public class EditCell<S, T> extends TableCell<S, T> {

    // Text field for editing
    // TODO: allow this to be a plugable control.
    private final TextField textField = new TextField();

    // Converter for converting the text in the text field to the user type, and vice-versa:
    private final StringConverter<T> converter ;

    public Torte1(StringConverter<T> converter) {
        this.converter = converter ;

        itemProperty().addListener((obx, oldItem, newItem) -> {
            if (newItem == null) {
                setText(null);
            } else {
                setText(converter.toString(newItem));
            }
        });
        setGraphic(textField);
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);

        textField.setOnAction(evt -> commitEdit(this.converter.fromString(textField.getText())));
        textField.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, wasFocused, isNowFocused) -> {
            if (! isNowFocused) {
                commitEdit(this.converter.fromString(textField.getText()));
            }
        });
        textField.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> {
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                textField.setText(converter.toString(getItem()));
                cancelEdit();
                event.consume();
            } else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT) {
                getTableView().getSelectionModel().selectRightCell();
                event.consume();
            } else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT) {
                getTableView().getSelectionModel().selectLeftCell();
                event.consume();
            } else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.UP) {
                getTableView().getSelectionModel().selectAboveCell();
                event.consume();
            } else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) {
                getTableView().getSelectionModel().selectBelowCell();
                event.consume();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Convenience converter that does nothing (converts Strings to themselves and vice-versa...).
     */
    public static final StringConverter<String> IDENTITY_CONVERTER = new StringConverter<String>() {

        @Override
        public String toString(String object) {
            return object;
        }

        @Override
        public String fromString(String string) {
            return string;
        }

    };

    /**
     * Convenience method for creating an EditCell for a String value.
     * @return
     */
    public static <S> Torte1<S, String> createStringEditCell() {
        return new Torte1<>(IDENTITY_CONVERTER);
    }


    // set the text of the text field and display the graphic
    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        System.out.println("Start Editing");

        super.startEdit();
        textField.setText(converter.toString(getItem()));
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        textField.requestFocus();
    }

    // revert to text display
    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
    }

    // commits the edit. Update property if possible and revert to text display
    @Override
    public void commitEdit(T item) {
        System.out.println("Commit Edit");

        // This block is necessary to support commit on losing focus, because the baked-in mechanism
        // sets our editing state to false before we can intercept the loss of focus.
        // The default commitEdit(...) method simply bails if we are not editing...
        if (! isEditing() && ! item.equals(getItem())) {
            TableView<S> table = getTableView();
            if (table != null) {
                TableColumn<S, T> column = getTableColumn();
                CellEditEvent<S, T> event = new CellEditEvent<>(table,
                        new TablePosition<S,T>(table, getIndex(), column),
                        TableColumn.editCommitEvent(), item);
                Event.fireEvent(column, event);
            }
        }

        super.commitEdit(item);

        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
    }

}
```

Класс, расширяющий `Application`

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TablePosition;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.function.Function;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class TableTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        TableView tableView = new TableView();
        tableView.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        tableView.setEditable(true);


        tableView.getColumns().add(createColumn("Name", Person::nameProperty));

        tableView.getItems().addAll(
                new Person("Carl"),
                new Person("Jon")
        );

        tableView.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
            TablePosition<?, ?> pos = tableView.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell();
            if (pos != null && event.getCode().isLetterKey()) {
                tableView.edit(pos.getRow(), pos.getTableColumn());
            }
        });
        Scene scene = new Scene(tableView);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setWidth(400);
        primaryStage.setHeight(400);
        primaryStage.setTitle("test");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private <T> TableColumn<T, String> createColumn(String title, Function<T, StringProperty> property) {
        TableColumn<T, String> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));

        col.setCellFactory(column -> EditCell.createStringEditCell());
        return col;
    }
    public static class Person {
        private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();

        public Person(String name) {
            setName(name);
        }

        public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public final void setName(final java.lang.String firstName) {
            this.nameProperty().set(firstName);
        }

    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Суть проблемы доступно [объясняют на англоязычном Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25291137/980828)

> Источником проблемы является `TableCellBehaviour`, а именно, его
>   реакция на событие `mousePressed`:
>
> - `mousePressed` вызывает `simpleSelect(..)`
> - При обнаружении одинарного клика, вызывается `edit(-1, null)`
> - который вызывает тот же метод в `TableView`
> - который приравнивает свой `editingCell` свойство `null`
> - `tableCell` слушает это свойство и реагирует отменой изменения

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь

Comment: Ох, как же жалко, если вы напишете в ячейку "Првет", потом поймете, что надо переместиться клавишей влево на несколько позиций в слове

Comment: @AndrewBystrov, ваш сарказм неуместен. Если у вас есть конструктивный ответ, который решит проблему качественнее, то поделитесь им с нами. Я со своей стороны с удовольствием готов проголосовать за.

Comment: Ответ на мой вопрос любезно предоставленный LEQADA полностью решают мою проблему,а то что нельзя передвигаться по полю с помощью стрелочек не такая уж и важная вещь для меня